# nested expression in mapbox

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have an expression that I am using in a mapbox map to decide which icon I want to show. It looks like this:

```
"icon-image": [
  "case",
  ["==", ["get", "matched"], "True"],
  "greenmarkertick",
  "redmarkercross",
]
```

I need to add another condition to this expression, as when matched is True but something else doesn't match, in this case:

```
["!=", ["get", "vehicle"], ["get", "standstill_vehicle"]]
```

I have tried adding this directly to my case expression, like so:

```
"icon-image": [
  "case",
  ["==", ["get", "matched"], "True"],
  "greenmarker",
  ["!=", ["get", "vehicle"], ["get", "standstill_vehicle"]],
  "orangemarker",
  "redmarker",
]
```

but this didn't work.

Basically what I need is an expression that checks if the the `matched` property is true and then checks to see if the vehicle properties match.

If they do display a green marker, if they don't display an orange marker. If `matched` is false then a red marker should be displayed.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realised that the positioning of the expressions in the `case` expression does matter. So , I solved my problem with the following expression:

```
"icon-image": [
  "case",
  ["all", ["==", ["get", "matched"], "True"], ["!=", ["get", "vehicle"], ["get", "standstill_vehicle"]]],
  "orangemarker",
  ["==", ["get", "matched"], "True"],
  "greenmarker",
  "redmarker",
]
```